# nginx: two websites under one ip address without dns

Tags: nginx

I have two folders `/var/www/html/website1` and `/var/www/html/website2`, and the ip of my server is `1.2.3.4`.

I would like to have :

- `1.2.3.4` pointing to `/var/www/html/website1`
- `1.2.3.4/ws2` pointing to `/var/www/html/website2`

What should I change or add to the `server` block of the two nginx configuration files `website1` and `website2` ?

Currently, I have the following configuration:

**website1**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

**website2**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost/ws2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need a `location` block.
In your case (for example):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    root /var/www/html/website1;

    location /ws2 {
        root /var/www/html/website2;
    }
}
```

Note: this is the most basic configuration imaginable, it may suit your needs, or you may have to alter it accordingly.

Comment: I'd prefer to have a file per configuration instead of configuring the website2 in the website1 file. Adding the `location` block to the website2 file doesn't work.

Comment: You configure a `server` and a `location` in this `server`. You don't have two websites, you only have one + a location. If you want to have two config files, you can define an include for `/ws2` inside your `1.2.3.4` server.

Comment: I get "404 Not Found" when trying the configuration in the main answer.

Comment: You need to adapt the paths in the snippet to the actual locations of your websites.